# Getting Error “Tenant Admin disabled this bot” for certain account ONLY. WHY?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Below are the Policy Settings of the tenant.

> **Global Org Policy: Beep is Allowed under Third-party Apps.**

[image]

> **Beep-test policy: Beep is Allowed under Third-party Apps and Custom App Permission Policy is Allowed for All apps.**

[image]

> Note 1: Beep is not a custom app as it is attested and approved by
> Microsoft
>
> Note 2: Both the test accounts belong to single tenant and are added
> are part of same team.

> Account 1: Has Global Org Policy
>
> When trying to open the Beep Extension gives the below error as shown
> in the image below, from the network tabs it shows the error 403 with
> The message bot disabled.

[image]

[image]

> **Account 2: Has Global Org Policy and Beep-test-policy**
>
> It works clearly as shown in the image below

[image]

> For reference these are the consent and permissions setting from Azure:

[image]

-------------x-------------x-------------x-------------x-------------x-------------x------------

**Updated**

**Edited the Beep-test policy and blocked the apps under the custom application.**

And also, assigned this policy to Account 1

But the result is still the same as above.

How much time does it take to reflect the change in policy?

Comment: Could you please provide both the tenant Ids (The one where the app is accessible and the other one where its throwing error)?

Comment: So, in the above I am just talking about the single tenant only!

Comment: Could you please provide the tenant details where you are having issue?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, tenant id of the above tenant showcasing issue: d7ebf946-7775-4c9b-b232-8b66ed67ade1

Comment: Thanks for providing tenant details. We have shared this issue info with engineering team. We will update this thread once we hear from them about the root cause of the issue.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, I added the update above.

Comment: There is an ICM for this issue and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we have further update. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please get the network traces for the scenario from both the working and not working tenants?

Answer (score 0):

@Prasad-MSFT I'm having the same issue with a recently created Teams App that uses a bot. I'm getting

{
"errorCode": 0,
"message": "The tenant admin disabled this bot",
"standardizedError": {
"errorCode": 209,
"errorSubCode": 1,
"errorDescription": "The tenant admin disabled this bot"
}
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please share the network traces along with tenant id for non-working tenant?